# Refactor to template class

Tags: c++, templates, refactoring

I am new to C++ language and learning templates.
I need to refactor the below classes into the templatized class. There are multiple duplications of code in the below classes except for the inherited base classes. The functionality of LineDerived and DotMatrixderived classes are same except their different bases classes and their virtual functions. Similarly for RealLine and RealDotMatrix classes.

```
  class LineDerived: public printer::printerType::Line
  {
   public:
    LineDerived(const std::wstring& str1) : _str(str1) {}
    virtual const std::wstring getData() override { return _str; }

   private:
     const std::wstring _str;
  };

 class DotMatrixderived: public printer::printerType::DotMatrix
  {
   public:
    DotMatrixderived(const std::wstring& str1) : _str(str1) {}
    virtual const std::wstring getData() override { return _str; }

   private:
     const std::wstring _str;
  };

 class RealLine : public printer::system::LineSystem
 {
   public:
     RealLine (const std::wstring& str1) : 
       LineSystem(boost::make_shared<LineDerived>(str1))
     {
     }

    virtual method1() { .. };
    virtual method2() { .. };
 };

 class RealDotMatrix : public printer::system::DotMatrixSystem
 {
   public:
     RealDotMatrix (const std::wstring& str1) : 
       DotMatrixSystem(boost::make_shared<DotMatrixderived>(str1))
     {
     }

    virtual method1() { .. };
    virtual method2() { .. };
 };


// Calling Part:
 RealLine line(strData);
 line.method1();
 line.method2();

 RealDotMatrix matrix(strData);
 matrix.method1();
 matrix.method2()
```

I would like to do something in which there could only one derived class with the Type as printer type i.e Line and DotMatrix, something like "derived<'Line'>" and "derived<<'DotMAtrix'>" and same are for real class. So the final calling should be like "real<'Line'> line(strData)" and "real<'DotMatrix'> dot(strData)".

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to do something in which there is only one derived class with the Type as printer type like derived<Line> and derived<DotMAtrix> and same is for real class. So the final calling should be like real<Line> line(strData) and real<DotMatrix> dot(strData).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to make your example a working example, but finaly I came up with this:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
// don't have boost now so I use stl to make the example work
namespace boost { using std::make_shared; using std::shared_ptr; }

namespace printer::printerType {
    class PrinterTypeBase {};

    class Line : public PrinterTypeBase {
    public:
        virtual const std::wstring getData() = 0;
        virtual ~Line(){}
    }; 

    class DotMatrix : public PrinterTypeBase {
    public:
        virtual const std::wstring getData() = 0;
        virtual ~DotMatrix(){}
    };
}

namespace printer::system {
    class LineSystem
    {
    public:
        LineSystem(boost::shared_ptr<printer::printerType::PrinterTypeBase>);

    };
    class DotMatrixSystem
    {
    public:
        DotMatrixSystem(boost::shared_ptr<printer::printerType::PrinterTypeBase>);
    };
}

template <typename T>
class Derived: public T::printerType
{
public:
    Derived(const std::wstring& str1) : _str(str1) {}
    virtual const std::wstring getData() override { return _str; }

private:
    const std::wstring _str;
};

template <typename T>
class Real : public T::systemType
{
public:
    Real(const std::wstring& str1) : 
    T::systemType(boost::make_shared<typename T::printerType>(str1))
    {
    }

    virtual void method1() { /*..*/ }
    virtual void method2() { /*..*/ }
    virtual ~Real() {}
};



struct DotMatrix
{
    using printerType = printer::printerType::DotMatrix;
    using systemType = printer::system::DotMatrixSystem;
};

struct Line
{
    using printerType = printer::printerType::Line;
    using systemType = printer::system::LineSystem;
};


int main(int, char**)
{
    const std::wstring strData;
    // Calling Part:
    Real<Line> line(strData);
    line.method1();
    line.method2();

    Real<DotMatrix> matrix(strData);
    matrix.method1();
    matrix.method2();
}
```